# Mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary' for object files from source files from the same visual studio 2015 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker

I have a common linker error in a situation where I do not understand why I get it. I changed a project from static linking (/MT) to dynamic linking (/MD). After this I get the following error:

```
Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't
match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in XY.obj    XXX [some folders]\XYZ.obj
```

The source files for XY and XYZ are both part of the same project. The project is compiled with /MD. I first thought that some files have not been updated in my rebuild, so I cleaned the build and rebuild the project. Since I still got the same error, I manually deleted the build folder containing the .obj files and rebuild the project. I still get the error.

A second effect I don't understand is that an included library (which I changed from the static version to the dynamic version) does not find several symbols:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strncat   LAAPTOF_Fuzzy_XOP   
[some folders]\ccc_vc120_md.lib(MxNET.obj)
```

etc...

When I include the static version of the library, these errors disappear but I get no error with respect to a runtime library mismatch, which I expected to get.

All these errors only show up for the 32 bit version of the project. The 64 bit version builds fine. I've checked all parameters and they are the same except where a different one is required for the 64 bit version.

Can anybody explain to me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. My project used to be a visual studio 2010 project. I've been warned that converting a project to a newer version of visual studio does not always run smooth, even if the converter tells you so. I don't know if this was really the problem, but after setting up a new project file, everything links correctly.